# populated HashMap created inside a Constructor returns null when instance object is referenced

Tags: java, constructor, hashmap

First time poster here.  I searched through stackoverflow but could not find any answers to this question, perhaps I'm phrasing it incorrectly.

I have one class where I create a HashMap inside of a Constructor (code below):

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Hippie extends Customer {

```
Hippie() {
    name = "Hippie";

    HashMap<String, Double> preferences = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    preferences.put("Donuts", 1.5);
    preferences.put("Biscotti", 0.5);

}
```

}

Unfortunately, when I create an instance of the "Hippie" object above, any reference to the HashMap in the instance object returns null even though the Constructor completes successfully.

public class SEJavaDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
Hippie Billy = new Hippie();
System.out.println(Billy.preferences);
System.out.println(Billy.name);

}
```

}

For example, the above code prints out:

null
Hippie

My ultimate goal is to be able to access the HashMap created by the Hippie constructor.  Any insights as to why it is returning null instead of HashMap would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In your constructor, preferences is a local variable.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Hippie extends Customer {

    public HashMap<String, Double> preferences;

    Hippie() {
        name = "Hippie";
        preferences = new HashMap<String,Double>();
    }
}
```

The `preferences` is not visible to the outside class, as its created within your `constructor`. You need to declare it as an instance variable and then initialize it in the constructor, to make it visible to outside classes.

Same goes with `name`.

Though this may solve your problem, its advised to do something like this:-

```
class Hippie extends Customer {

        private HashMap<String, Double> preferences

        Hippie() {
            name = "Hippie";
            preferences = new HashMap<String,Double>();
        }

    // have a getter for the hashmap
    public HashMap<String,Double> getMap(){
        return preferences;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:-

```
Hippie billy = new Hippie(); // Couldn't digest `Billy` as object name.
System.out.println(billy.getMap());
```

Comment: This answer is the correct solution to the stated problem, but I don't like having a public Map.  Where's the encapsulation and information hiding?  Don't follow this as an example of good implementation.

Comment: Thanks R.J. and duffymo.  I'll try implementing a get function to return the HashMap, hopefully that will work.  Thanks!

Comment: No, don't return the Map, either.  That's not private - you're giving out a reference for anyone to alter that wants to.  And it's not a good abstraction.  Why does anyone care that you chose to implement using a Map?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a local reference to the HashMap As a result. It's scope is limited to the constructor itself. Create a instance variable for the same and try populating it in the constructor. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This design is hurting my eyes.

There's no reason on earth to use extends here.  IS-A `Hippie` always a `Customer`?  Don't all `Customers` have preferences?

There's no encapsulation or information hiding at all.  If you must write this, think about it more like this:

```
public class Customer {
    private Map<String, Double> preferences; 

    public Customer() {
        this.preferences = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
    }

    public Double getPreference(String key) {
        return this.preferences.get(key);
    }

    public void setPreference(String key, Double value) {
        this.preferences.put(key, value);
    }

    public void removePreference(String key) {
       this.preferences.remove(key);
    }

    public boolean hasPreference(String key) {
        return this.preferences.containsKey(key);
    }

    // ONLY if you must.
    public Map<String, Double> getMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.preferences); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Along these same encapsulation/info-hiding lines, the getMap() could be replaced with a get for the map's keySet.  This would allow others to see what keys exist, but would force them back through your other methods to actually interact with the data.  This could be especially valuable if you wanted to add additional logic to your get/set/remove methods.